# Selecting multiple options using Laracasts\Integrated

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel-5

I am using Laracasts\Integrated library to test my web application. I have a form like this:

```
<select multiple name="resource[]"> 
<option value="Coal">Coal</option>
<option value="Another">Aluminum</option>
.
.
</select>
```

My test case is:

```
$this->select('resource[]' , ['Coal' , 'Another']);
```

i get error:

```
Symfony\Component\CssSelector\Exception\SyntaxErrorException:  Expected identifier│ or "*", but <delimiter "]" at 11> found.
```

Please help me .

Comment: where do you put this line ? what does `this` holds ? [which object]  as laravel doesn't come with support for `html`/`form` classes you will need to follow this guide - [Laravel Collective - Forms & HTML](http://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.1/html) to be able do such thing.

Comment: I am doing the test using Laracasts/Integrated library ..   (https://github.com/laracasts/Integrated) .. .... 
 
i am testing one web site and i need to make some test case:

public function make_new_contract( ) 
{
    $this->select('resource[]' , ['Coal' , 'Another']);

Comment: Make sure you're using latest version of the package and check if the method `makeRequestUsingForm` inside `src/Extensions/Laravel.php` looks like [handles sub arrays in form](https://github.com/laracasts/Integrated/commit/93cf561285d834bbd4c0063a21cc1956c7e757dc) if that doesnt work you could try this sulotion - [Laravel 5.1 - Testing a multiple selectbox](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32231264/3208719)

Comment: @Gal thanks for the answer it worked .....  i have another problem ....  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32713966/php-unit-with-square-bracket-for-text-field-name 
i hope you can solve this ... please help once .... i am new to stack overflow

Answer (score 1):

Solution i got with the help Gal:

my test case:

```
/**@test*/
public function add_new()
{
 $this->storeInput('resource', ['6PGM+Au' ,'Coal'], true)
      ->andPress('Submit')
}


   public function storeInput($element, $text, $force = false)
    {
        if ($force) {
            $this->inputs[$element] = $text;
            return $this;
        }
        else {
            return parent::storeInput($element, $text);
        }
    }
```