# PHP Unit with square bracket ( [ ) for text field name

Tags: laravel-5

I am testing a web project using Laracasts\Integrated library (with PHPUNIT).

I have a following HTML form:

```
<input type="text" name = "company[0][name]" id="comp_0" />
```

I have the following test case:

```
/** @test **/
public function add_new()
{
   $this->type('New Company' , 'company[0][name]');
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Symfony\Component\CssSelector\Exception\SyntaxErrorException: Expected identifier or "*", but <number at 20> found.
```

I am searching and trying alot ... but i am not able to get the solution for it.

Comment: Laravel-5 blade template will not allow that. I don't know why are you trying to use brackets in name. Your code looks like an array select.

Comment: I am testing one web application , i am doing black box testing , even i don't know the code .... why the developers have used that .... but any how i solved the problem.

Comment: Answer your own question so we can see how you did it. This is fair play for this community. You can award your own answer as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution was simple:

```
/** @test **/
public function add_this()
{
  $this->storeInput('company[0][name]' , 'New Company Here On Nepal' ,true);
}


  public function storeInput($element, $text, $force = false)
    {
        if ($force) {
            $this->inputs[$element] = $text;
            return $this;
        }
        else {
            return parent::storeInput($element, $text);
        }
    }
```